# How to simplify this 'for' loop?

Tags: scala

```
val xsa = List(1,2,3)
val xsb = List(1,2,3)
for (i <- 0 until xsa.size) {
    val a = xsa(i)
    val b = xsb(i)
    println(a + "_" + b)
}
```

I want to simplify the length equals' List or Array. I hoped to do it like this:

```
for (a <- xsa; b <- xsb)
    println(a + "_" + b)
```

But why does it only iterate `xsb` once?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
for ((a,b) <- xsa zip xsb)
  println(a + "_" + b)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
(xsa, xsb).zipped foreach ((a, b) => println (a + "_" + b))
```

Or

```
(xsa, xsb).zipped map (_ + "_" + _) foreach println
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Seq.zip`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html)

```
val x = xsa.zip(xsb)
for ((a, b) <- x)
    println(a + "_" + b)
```